# Android/java Parsing JSON with numbered data

Tags: java, android, json

I have been looking for parsing JSON data in java/android. unfortunately, there is no JSON that same as mine. i have JSON data that include weird number, looks like :

```
{
"formules": [{"1":
    {
  "formule": "Linear Motion",
  "url": "qp1"
},"2":
{
  "formule": "Constant Acceleration Motion",
  "url": "qp2"
},"3":
{
  "formule": "Projectile Motion",
  "url": "qp3"
}
}
]
}
```

Please help me how to parse this in Java/android. Thanks

Comment: this is valid json...first create jsonobject, then get array from the jsonobject, and you will get it

Comment: yet another JSON problem ... *there is no JSON that same as mine* maybe, but there is bazillions similar, if you don't get it from similar JSON example, you should give up with programming at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("formules");
JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

Now you can access object "1" as

```
JSONObject json = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("1");
```

or use iterator to iterate as below

```
Iterator keys = jsonObject1.keys();
while(keys.hasNext()) {
            // loop to get the dynamic key
            String currentDynamicKey = (String)keys.next();
            JSONObject json = jsonObject1.getJSONObject(currentDynamicKey);

        }
```

let me know if it works

Comment: hi apk, its works!! thank you so much. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing Json in Android, I have found the Gson Library to be helpful

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3

What it would require is creating a pojo class that represents your object. Might look something like

```
public class ClassPojo
{
private Formules[] formules;

public Formules[] getFormules ()
{
    return formules;
}

public void setFormules (Formules[] formules)
{
    this.formules = formules;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [formules = "+formules+"]";
}
}
public class Formules
{
private Formule 3;

private Forumle 2;

private Formule 1;



}

public class Formule
{
private String formule;

private String url;

public String getFormule ()
{
    return formule;
}

public void setFormule (String formule)
{
    this.formule = formule;
}

public String getUrl ()
{
    return url;
}

public void setUrl (String url)
{
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [formule = "+formule+", url = "+url+"]";
}
}
```

then to convert it to and from JSon,you could use

```
//Convert to JSON
ClassPojo pojo = new ClassPojo();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(pojo);

//COnvert back to Java object
ClassPojo pojo = gson.fromJson(json,ClassPojo.class);
```